# Looking for a phrase that involves comparison to overlooked stepsister

Tags: phrases, comparisons

In certain places I have read a phrase that involves comparing someone/something to an overlooked stepsister (originating from Cinderella maybe). It's supposed to convey the neglected status of that person/thing. Does anyone know what exactly the wording is and how it is properly used? I can't seem to find it online (google takes it too literally) but I am sure I have heard it used. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't just "The Cinderella X"? That's often used to express the fact that some public service has low status and, often  that it is underfunded as a result. In the UK we often hear claims that some parts of psychiatric medicine are "the Cinderella services in the NHS".

Comment: "Cinderella story" is another common idiom, referring to someone achieving unexpected good fortune. It's often used in sports when an underdog team is on a winning streak.